# Resize image on mouse click in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

This code displays an image and works:

```
import pygame

from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((900,900))

lion = pygame.image.load("lion.jpg")

while true:
   screen.blit(lion, (0,0))
   pygame.display.update()
```

I also want be able to right click the image to adjust its size. For example:

```
pygame.event.get()
buttonpress = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
press = pygame.key.get_pressed()
screen.blit(lion,(100-(lion.get_width()/2, 100-(lion.get_height()/2))))
pygame.event.quit
```

However, as soon as I click on the pygame window, it stops responding and I cannot do anything to it.

Comment: Check the "comments" section [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#comment_pygame_mouse_get_pressed). It has examples on how to correctly parse mouse events.

Answer (score 1):

screen.blit() takes two arguments, surface and destination. It seems like you are trying to use it to resize your image. You could use pygame.transform.scale() which takes the surface and size arguments. For Example:

```
done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT: #so you can close your window without it crashing or giving an error
            done = True
    pressed_buttons = pygame.mouse.get_pressed() #get a tuple of boolean values for the pressed buttons
    if pressed_buttons[2]: #if the right mouse button is down
        adjusted_lion_image = pygame.transform.scale(lion, (lion.get_wdith() / 2, lion.get_height() / 2)) #set the adjusted image to an image equal to half the size of the original image

    else: #if the right mouse button is not down
        adjusted_lion_image = lion #set the adjusted image back to the lion image

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0)) #fill the screen with black before we draw to make it look cleaner
    screen.blit(adjusted_lion_image, (0, 0)) #blit the adjusted image
    pygame.display.update() #update the screen

pygame.quit() #make sure this is OUTSIDE of the while loop.
```

This should accomplish what you want. You also might want to add a .convert() after loading the lion image to convert the image to one pygame can use more readily:

```
lion = pygame.image.load("lion.jpg").convert()
```